# Python, While-True loop that gets an integer and returns a word with same length

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm not sure how to begin this function. Conceptually I think it should look through a list of words, and until a word with the same length as the integer given is found, returns that word.

## example for lenword(num)

```
def lenword(4):
   wrdlst = [ 'i' , 'to', 'two', 'four']
while True:
#stuck here

#returns 'four'
```

please help!

Comment: *"Conceptually I think it should..."* - how on earth are you going to write a function if you aren't even sure what it should do?

Comment: What if theres more that one four letter word in the list?

Comment: If you learn anything from this let it be that there are 1,000 ways to do anything in Python.  Pick the one that makes the most sense to you and roll with it.  There simply is no best, or even wrong, answer.

Comment: Yea, and that you should be specific about what you want and how you want it. Or you'll get 6 answers doing the same thing, each one slightly different than the last. Haha.

Answer (score 3):

```
def lenword(n):
    wrdlst = [ 'i' , 'to', 'two', 'four']
    # for every item in the list, if the length of that item is
    # equal to n (in this case 4) then print the item, and return it.
    for word in wrdlst:
        if len(word) == n:
            print word
            return word

# call the function
four_letter_word = lenword(4)
```

Or if there's more than one four letter word in your list.

```
def lenword(n):
    wrdlst = [ 'i' , 'to', 'two', 'four']
    found_words = []
    # for every item in the list, if the length of that item is
    # equal to n (in this case 4) then print the item, and return it.
    for word in wrdlst:
        if len(word) == n:
            found_words.append(word)
    return found_words

# call the function
four_letter_words = lenword(4)

# print your words from the list
for item in four_letter_words:
    print item
```

Comment: And I guess there's always the possibility that you want to find the last 4letter word....

Comment: You could just `return [word for word in wrdlst if len(word) == n]`

Comment: Isn't that what I did? Just on one line?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
def lenword(word_length):
    wordlist = [ 'i' , 'to', 'two', 'four']
    for word in wordlist:
        if len(word) == word_length:
            # found word with matching length
            return word
    # not found, returns None
```

Using [**closures**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) to create specialized searcher for a specific list of words can make it nicer:

```
def create_searcher(words):
    def searcher(word_length, words=words):
        for word in words:
            if len(word) == word_length:
                # found word with matching length
                return word
        # not found, returns None
    return searcher
```

And use it like this:

```
# create search function specialized for a list of words
words_searcher = create_searcher(['list', 'of', 'words'])
# use it
words_searcher(4) # returns 'list'
words_searcher(3) # returns None
words_searcher(2) # returns 'of'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list going to be in order, such that the nth element has a length of n+1 then you can just:

```
wrdlist = [ 'i' , 'to', 'two', 'four']

def lenword(n):
   return wrdlist[n-1]

lenword(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lenword(n, words):
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == n:
            return word

>>> wrdlst = [ 'i' , 'to', 'two', 'four']
>>> lenword(4, wrdlst)
'four'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you function definition is off. When defining the function, you choose a name for the arguments, and then you would pass the value of `4` when you *call* the function.

```
def lenword(length):
    wrdlst = ['i', 'to', 'two', 'for']
    for word in wrdlst:
        if len(word) == length:
            return word
    return None
```

And then you would call this function like:

```
print lenword(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In first place you have to define the list of words like you did. The next step is understand the concepts you need to learn, like length of a string and loops.

So it should look like this:

```
def lenword(word_length):
    wrdlst = [ 'i' , 'to', 'two', 'four']
    for word in wrdlist:
        if len(word) == word_length:
            return word
```

You could improve this by giving the string array as a parameter to the function.

Comment: `word.len()` do not exist edit your anser to use `len(word)` instead.